# why the method of spy can not be stubbed?

Tags: mockito, stub, spy

I wonder whether the spy created by Mockito can be stubbed to returen a value. In the following code, the spy.get(0) is stubbed to return a string "not reachable". So I think the assertEquals() should be passed. But the test method ends up with throwing an IndexOutOfBoundsException exception. So, I think the real version of get() must be called rather than the stubbed version. Does the spy can be stubbed?

```
@Test
public void doReturnUsage() throws Exception {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> spy = spy(list);
    when(spy.get(0)).thenReturn("not reachable");
    assertEquals("not reachable", spy.get(0));
}
```

Comment: Your example, and how to fix it, is literally in the documentation: https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.23.0/org/mockito/Mockito.html#spy

Answer (score 0):

When you are using @Spy, the syntax is slightly different then when using a normal Injected instance.

```
Mockito.doReturn("not reachable").when(spy).get(0);
```

Spy as usefull when you want to "mock" a public method which is under the class which you are testing. 
e.g.

```
Class A {
  public void methodA() {
    // do something
  }
  public void methodB() {
    // do something 
    call methodA();
   // do something else 
  }
}
```

Here, public method "methodA" of class A is called from public method "methodB". So when writing testcase for "methodB", we mock call to "methodA" using spy. And we independently test "methodA"

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I have no idea why we should use doReturn() rather than thenReturn(). IMO, the doReturn() is used to stub void method. The get() method is not a void method at all.

Comment: when you are using spy, this is the syntax we need to follow. i.e. doReturn vs thenReturn. 

And doNothing() is used to stub void method.

Comment: How can I decide when to use doReturn, when to use thenReturn?

Comment: size() can be stubbed: when(spy.size()).thenReturn(100);

Comment: Stubbing get(0) will throw an exception: when(spy.get(0)).thenReturn("good");

Answer (score 0):

Consider another example:

```
@Test
public void thenReturnUsage() {
    List<String> list = new LinkedList<String>();
    List<String> spy = spy(list);
    // doReturn(100).when(spy).size(); 
    when(spy.size()).thenReturn(100);
    int size = spy.size();
    assertEquals(100, size);
}
```

This test pass again. But the spy.size() is stubbed with when().thenReturn() rather than doReturn().when(). Why?